# How do I make collision objects in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a 2D game where I need objects to scroll up the screen while the player avoids the objects. I need the game to end when the player hits the objects.

it should look something like this:

[image: game]

So far I can move the skier(image) left and right:

[image]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

#canvas dimensions
w = 800
h = 1000
x = w/2
y = h/2

#canvas 
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg="white")
my_canvas.pack(pady=20)

#import player image
img=Image.open(r"C:/Users/Gebruiker/Pictures/player.png")

resized = img.resize((300,225), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

new_image = my_canvas.create_image(150,100, anchor=NW,image = new_img)

#player movement
def left(event):
    x = -20
    y = 0
    my_canvas.move(new_image,x,y)

def right(event):
    x = 20
    y = 0
    my_canvas.move(new_image,x,y)

root.bind("<Left>", left)
root.bind("<Right>", right)
```

How do I randomly spawn objects at regular intervals? I think I need some function to scroll the canvas as the objects spawn.

Similar posts usually had 1 object moving in a changing direction. However, I need lots of objects to spawn continuously.

Also, how do I make a collision border to stop the player going off the canvas?

Comment: sorry, I added the same image twice

Comment: this is a tall order. I won't ask why you didn't chose pygame, but it looks like you need to start with a game loop

Comment: [Heres](https://coderslegacy.com/python/pygame-scrolling-background/) how to do a scrolling background game exactly like you describe if you change your mind about tkinter

Comment: @AnthonyL thanks I will give it a try! I'm not using pygame because school said I can't :(

Comment: [heres](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/eventloop.html) a tutorial for tkinter loops